# put request in angular sends empty form data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make a put request.

The api requires an array of numbers as request parameter

```
    $http({

    'requestpath/putrequesturl',
    {
        categories: [categorylist]
    },
    {
        'method': 'PUT',
        'authToken': authToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }

});
```

the data is sent as

```
requestpath/putrequesturl?categories=%5B5,19,12%5D
```

the query string parameter shows correct data, but `Form Data` in chrome dev tools is empty.
I tried this without `content-type` too, but it does not work

How can i make this request to send data as Form Data (Request body)

Edit: this is what api requires to get sent (if this is necessary):

`Parameter: categories`  `type:array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $http params looks a little odd. Maybe you are trying to do something like this..

```
$http({
   method: "PUT",
   uri: 'requestpath/putrequesturl',
   headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "authToken": authToken // assuming this should be in the header
   },
   data: {
      categories: [categorylist]
   }
})
```

Comment: this works, but i am unable to send an array .
data get sent as 

categories[]:1
categories[]:2
categories[]:3
not as categories[1,2,3,4]

Answer (score 0):

This is how the method put should seems

```
 $http({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: uri,
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"},
    data: someData
});
```

or

```
$http.put(url, data, config)
```